# Sending notifications to Amazon SNS on AWS DMS task progress

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-dms

Is it possible to pull AWS DMS replication task percentage progress and use that to  create an AWS Lambda function for sending notifications to Amazon SNS for let's say, every 10% completion? I can't find any metrics/event categories anywhere in relation to this while I was browsing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a lambda here. You can monitor the progress using CloudWatch then set up an SNS notification.

- monitoring: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Monitoring.html
- sns for cloudwatch:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/US_SetupSNS.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have already read through the links and like I said for CloudWatch, I couldn't find any specific metric listed that gives out a percentage completion that I can use.Not sure if I missed something but if you can give out a more detailed response then please let me know.